# Print value after certain word and upto mentioned word

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

So I have a `file.txt` that goes like this

```
abc, def, class="my_name", this is good
def, hij, this is getting bad, and bad, class="my_class"
trying to achive my goal class="still_looking"
```

So I need a value of class, ie:

```
my_name
my_class
still_looking
```

I tried sed and grep but no success.

```
sed "s/[^class=]*,\([^\"]*\),^C/\1/" file.txt

grep -oP '(?<=class)[0-9][a-z][A-Z]+' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture and output all non `"` characters after `class="` string:

```
sed 's/.*class="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file.txt
```

or if multiple `class` per line, with grep, :

```
grep -oP '(?<=class=")[^"]*' file.txt
```

Comment: So in fact the `grep` approach is better since it covers this case when two matches occur in a single line.

Comment: @AhsanNaseem in such case, consider accepting the answer so that it is clear that the problem is solved -and you also grant some credit to SLePort.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
grep -oP 'class="\K.*?(?=")'
```